# "Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. at mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml", but can when I copy, delete and re-paste?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, weblogic

Running Maven, Eclipse, and Weblogic, when I try to Run As Server onto my local server, I get this error:

"Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. at mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"

Then, when I go back into the xml, select all, copy, delete, and paste, error goes away and I'm able to run the web app just fine on the server. Can anyone explain why?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="src.srcc.sndao" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Sometimes eclipse doesn't refresh your files until you modify them.

Comment: What's giving you the error, Eclipse? Maven? Weblogic?

Comment: Weblogic popup error

Error(s) found in module 'testWebApp'. Publish was cancelled. See "Problems" view for details.
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. at mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml